# Can Jabber tell my client how long a user has been logged in for?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

When we used AIM at work, my client reported the time a user had logged on, how long he'd been logged on, and how long he'd been idle. After switching to an Openfire server, my client (Adium) no longer seems to have this information. Is this a limitation of Jabber, Openfire, or my client? Do I just need to find the right configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the debug window to take a peek at what Pidgin is requesting, it doesn't seem to include the logged in time.  I would assume due to the open nature of the XMPP protocol such a request *is* possible.

Example:

```
(10:38:07) jabber: Sending (ssl): <iq type='get' id='purple36ba35f' to='XXX'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq> 
(10:38:07) jabber: Sending (ssl): <iq type='get' id='purple36ba360' to='XXX'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:version'/></iq> 
(10:38:07) jabber: Sending (ssl): <iq type='get' id='purple36ba361' to='XXX'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/></iq> 
(10:38:08) jabber: Recv (ssl)(847): <iq type="result" id="purple36ba35f" from="XXX" to="XXX"><vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"> ... </vCard></iq> 
(10:38:08) jabber: Recv (ssl)(236): <iq type="result" to="XXX" id="purple36ba360" from="XXX"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version"><name>Pidgin</name><version>2.5.6 (libpurple2.5.6)</version></query></iq> 
(10:38:08) jabber: Recv (ssl)(177): <iq type="result" id="purple36ba361" to="XXX" from="XXX"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:last" seconds="0"/></iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question...

The OpenFire **SERVER** shows the last time someone logged out and I know the event logs can record the logon/logout events.

Pidgin and Spark (and old version I have) don't appear to show it.

I'm inclined to think its a client issue because we're using SecuredIM (http://www.securedim.com) which is based on OpenFire and the SecuredIM administration model shows me the "Last Activity" date/time of each user.

This tells me that the SERVER clearly has the info... the client just doesn't have it.

Comment: Or maybe the protocol doesn't allow sending it?

Answer (score 0):

We use Openfire, I have been using kopete client and I can see "Online Since" with time the user logged in to our jabber server.